# Activity recognition not working on several devices

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

the sample code from http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html
doesn't work in Nexus S and Motorola droid devices (and probably on other devices also), 
confirm working on Nexus 7 2013 and Samsung Galaxy Young,

this occurs after update to latest play services 5.0.89, in my recall two months ago, it works fine on all devices,

try to switch using GoogleApiClient, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

confirm working after enable network Provider on location access, I think this is a bug on play service